# Populating Data into Text field through REST API

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, people-picker

I am stuck at a small place, could you all kindly help me.

Below code shows, receiving People Picker Column data(Should Cost Modeler Field Name) into Text field which is (Employee Name) and converting that Employee Name Text field to drop down.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
var employeeName=$("input[title^='Employee Name']").val();
$("input[title^='Employee Name']").hide();
$("input[title^='Employee Name']").after("<select id='EmployeeField' class='ms-RadioText'><option value=''></option></select>");
var allEmployeeNames=getAllEmployeeNames();
$.each(allEmployeeNames,function(i,employee){
    if(employeeName==employee.Should_x0020_Cost_x0020_Modeler.Title){
        $("#EmployeeField").append("<option selected='selected' value='"+employee.Should_x0020_Cost_x0020_Modeler.Title+"'>"+employee.Should_x0020_Cost_x0020_Modeler.Title+"</option>");
    }else{
        $("#EmployeeField").append("<option value='"+employee.Should_x0020_Cost_x0020_Modeler.Title+"'>"+employee.Should_x0020_Cost_x0020_Modeler.Title+"</option>");
    }       
});
$("#EmployeeField").change(function(){
    $("input[title^='Employee Name']").val($(this).val());
  });
   })
   function getAllEmployeeNames(){
    var results;
$.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists(guid'4BFF0A20-43A2-4444-881C-18932D468E54')/items?$select=Should_x0020_Cost_x0020_Modeler/Title&$expand=Should_x0020_Cost_x0020_Modeler/Id",
    type: "GET",
    async:false,
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    },
    success: function (data) {
        if(data.d.results.length>0){
            results=data.d.results;
        }
    },
    error: function (data) {
        //alert("Error");
    }
});
return results;
    }
  </script>
```

The above code populates the the dropdown but it gives undefined as value in dropdown . Below image shows can convey the message.
[image]

Hope you guys can help me out on this. 
Thanks.

Comment: Debug using F12 and you will see that 'employee.Should_x0020_Cost_x0020_Modeler.Title' return null/undefined.

Comment: i did and the console shows employee is not defined but when i use other people picker field it gets populated. idk why this is happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the "Should Cost Modeler" column allow multiple data. Modify the code as below.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var employeeName=$("input[title^='Employee Name']").val();
    $("input[title^='Employee Name']").hide();
    $("input[title^='Employee Name']").after("<select id='EmployeeField' class='ms-RadioText'><option value=''></option></select>");
    var allEmployeeNames=getAllEmployeeNames();
    $.each(allEmployeeNames,function(i,employee){
        $.each(employee.Should_x0020_Cost_x0020_Modeler.results,function(j,item){
            if(employeeName==item.Title){
                $("#EmployeeField").append("<option selected='selected' value='"+item.Title+"'>"+item.Title+"</option>");
            }else{
                if(item.Title!=undefined){
                    $("#EmployeeField").append("<option value='"+item.Title+"'>"+item.Title+"</option>");
                }           
            }   
        });         
    });
    //remove duplicate values
    $("#EmployeeField option").each(function() {
        $(this).siblings('[value="'+$(this).val()+'"]').remove();
    });
    $("#EmployeeField").change(function(){
        $("input[title^='Employee Name']").val($(this).val());
    });
})
function getAllEmployeeNames(){
    var results;
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists(guid'4BFF0A20-43A2-4444-881C-18932D468E54')/items?$select=Should_x0020_Cost_x0020_Modeler/Title&$expand=Should_x0020_Cost_x0020_Modeler/Id",
        type: "GET",
        async:false,
        headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if(data.d.results.length>0){
                results=data.d.results;
            }
        },
        error: function (data) {
        //alert("Error");
        }
    });
    return results;
}
</script>
```

Comment: but the column is not empty. There are values in it. I tried your above code and i do not get any value in the Dropdown.

Comment: Check if the "Should Cost Modeler" column internal name is "Should_x0020_Cost_x0020_Modeler" again, go to list settings-> right click this column and check the internal name.

Comment: i have checked it more than 5 times and the name is same but i still could not find any difference in the name. Idk how should i tackle this problem

Comment: Access "http://yoursiteurl/_api/web/lists(guid'4BFF0A20-43A2-4444-881C-18932D468E54')/items?$select=Should_x0020_Cost_x0020_Modeler/Title&$expand=Should_x0020_Cost_x0020_Modeler/Id" in your browser, and check if it works. Modify your site url.

Comment: tried no outcome. Is anything else left?

Comment: Check my reply above, I suggest you use IE to check it. And provide the screenshots about the result xml data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84226/discussion-between-jayant-khushalani-and-lz-msft).

Comment: I found that the field that i am trying to call has m:type="Collection(Edm.Int32) type data not m:type="Edm.Int32"

Comment: Because the "Should Cost Modeler" column allow multiple data, I modified the code in my reply, check it.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked. After so many iterations, But i am getting duplicate values any way to remove those duplication?

Comment: Check the reply again, I have added the code to remove the duplicate values. If the solutions works, you can make the reply as reply as answer, it will make others who stuck with the similar issue easier to search for valid solutions in this forum.